# Shutter or Gnome cannot take snapshot while a right-click menu is open

Tags: screenshot, ubuntu-10.10

for example i select some text and right click, leave it like that (i.e. right-click menu open) and hit PrtScr button but shutter does not take the snapshot (same for gnome's default snapshot app...yes the keybindings are correct). is there some settings in gnome that i have to play with?
(i use: ubuntu meerkat 64bit)

Answer (score 1):

Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot

Set a some seconds delay, open the needed context menu and wait.

Tried on 10.10 32bit, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work on 64bit.